# Plugin System without rebuilding for each OS?

Tags: c++, c, plugins, cross-platform

I'm making a game that will allow content development and I'd like it to be sort of a DLL based system. But, my game works for Linux (X86 arch) , Mac OSX and 32 bit Windows. Is there a way I could allow content developers to compile only one thing and have it work based on the platform? I fear it might get confusing if there are 3 versions per plugin. What could I do?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with platform-indenpendent scripting languages?  Lua, Python?  That kind of thing?  They work with C++.  They plugin?  Are they possibilities?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can decide to use a cross-platform scripting environment like Lua for plugins. This is essentially what most cross-platform games do.

Answer (score 3):

You could possibly use LLVM as a middle ground if you want C or C++ plugins.  Have plugin devs ship LLVM assembly/bytecode, and use LLVM's runtime code emission to compile it to native code when you load it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless things have changed drastically since I last looked at cross platform development if you are using c/c++ you need to compile and link for the operating system you are going to execute on.

So if you want to run on 3 operating systems you need 3 binaries.

Comment: You could alternatively have devs ship sources and invoke the compiler on the user's system, but that doesn't work well on Windows unless you ship GCC with the app.

Answer (score 0):

weren't e.g. Xfree86 and/or Xorg drivers (video? or something else?)

"cross-OS" so they could be built once and "run" on any OS, at least on the same CPU....

no idea how that works ... a virtual machine of some kind perhaps???

probably overkill ...but certainly possible.....